SwiftUI: How do you get the keyboard to not push up controls at very bottom of view, but still push up view to adjust for active TextField?
In SwiftUI on iOS, I have the following .sheet which displays a DisclosureGroup which contains a DisclosureGroup within it that has a TextField. At the very bottom of the .sheet are two buttons "Cancel" and "Enter" to allow the user to submit data / dismiss it:
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View
{
    @State private var sheetIsPresented: Bool = false
    @State private var outerDisclosureIsExpanded: Bool = false
    @State private var innerDisclosureIsExpanded: Bool = false
    @State private var textFieldUserInput: String = ""
    
    var body: some View
    {
            Button("OK")
            {
                self.sheetIsPresented = true
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: self.$sheetIsPresented)
            {
                VStack
                {
                    Form
                    {
                        Section(header: Text("Section"))
                        {
                            DisclosureGroup("Outer Disclosure Group", isExpanded: self.$outerDisclosureIsExpanded)
                            {
                                ForEach(1...20, id: \.self)
                                {
                                    index in Text("Value \(index)")
                                }
                                DisclosureGroup("Inner Disclosure Group", isExpanded: self.$innerDisclosureIsExpanded)
                                {
                                    TextField("Enter name", text: self.$textFieldUserInput)
                                    
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                HStack
                {
                    Button("Cancel")
                    {
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(.bordered).padding()
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Button("Enter")
                    {
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                    .padding()
                }
            }
        }
}

When I activate the TextField contained in the inner DisclosureGroup, the keyboard pushes up the "Cancel" and "Enter" buttons at the very bottom of the view, as well as adjusting the view so that the TextField is visible as the user types:

I would like to make it so the "Cancel" and "Enter" buttons are not pushed up, that the keyboard goes over them so they are not visible, yet still pushes the View up so that the TextField is visible to the user as they type. .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom) does not work with this code for some reason, but even when I've tried it in other places of my code, it will push the keyboard on top of the TextField as well as the "Cancel" and "Enter" buttons. Is there another way to accomplish what I've asked about?
